# How to write to a shared folder on an Unix machine from code inside an ASMX service?

Tags: asmx, file-writing

One of our team is working on an ASMX service. The service use to write some files on the same machine. We used to provide rights to the ASPNET user on the target folder.

Now, the policy has changed and the writing need to be done on a file system provided as a shared folder (mapped drive) from an Unix machine. Since then, there is an exception of authorisation.

Can somebody guide for the solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the wait period over on SO, and with my continuous trials, I could come out with some work around. So now I use a `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string fileName, string arguments, string userName, SecureString password, string domain)` and the command is simply a copy command. This solves the issue.